# When can a machine designed to solve equations of degree less than $n$ over the complex numbers solve an equation of degree $m \geq n?$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

If a "machine" can solve any equation of degree less than $4$ over the complex numbers, then it can solve degree $4$ equations using the quartic formula which relies only on square roots (degree $2)$ and cube roots (degree $3).$ Is this the only case where a machine can solve general higher degree equations that what it is designed to solve? I have a hunch that this special case has something to do with the nontrivial homomorphism from the group $A_4$ to the group $A_3$ with kernel $V.$ Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, this is essentially what the whole classic story of Galois theory and the unsolvability of the quintic tells you. For $A_n, n \ge 5$ there is no corresponding homomorphism to a smaller symmetric or alternating group because of simplicity.